# How to convert many mp3 files in wav format in R

Tags: r, mp3

I have many mp3 files in one folder how can I convert every mp3 files in wav format in one go using R programming?

Following code work for me to convert one mp3 to wav format but how can I convert every mp3 file in a folder to wav format?

```
r <- readMP3("D:\\5366374684\\0297B65BR095V53DIHAKG2LAES00H7AT\\0297B65BR095V53DIHAKG2LAES00H7AT_2022-09-26_23-19-01_0.mp3")  
writeWave(r,"D:\\tmp.wav",extensible=FALSE)
```

Thanks for any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all files are in your current working directory,

```
library(monitoR)
mp_list <-list.files(pattern = ".mp3")
wav_list <- stringr::str_replace_all(mp_list, ".mp3", ".wav")
i_list <-  seq(length(mp_list))

for(i in i_list) {
    r <- readMP3(filename = mp_list[i])
    writeWave(r, wav_list[i], extensible=FALSE)
}
```